# unattended-upgrade of only security fixes for Sury PHP?

Tags: php, unattended-upgrades

I installed PHP 8.1 on a Debian 10 server by adding the [PHP Sury repository](https://deb.sury.org/) as an `apt` source at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php-sury.list`.  That all works fine.

I have `unattended-upgrades` installed and running to update the system.  I would now like to update the config to also update PHP packages from that repo.

I've added this to my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
    // Only security updates for Debian:
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";

    // Added this line for PHP:
    "origin=deb.sury.org,archive=${distro_codename},codename=${distro_codename}";
```

And this works fine - a dry-run shows all available PHP updates would be installed.

However, similarly to how I only allow security-related updates for Debian packages to be installed unattended this way, I'd prefer to only allow security-related updates for those PHP packages to auto-install.  Is there a way to do this, are there keywords I can add to that line in the config file to filter for only something flagged as a security update?  I don't know where to find what keywords exist for the updates, nor if a "*security*" keyword or similar exists.

##### UPDATE

The [Packages](https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages) file for my distro lists some packages as `Priority: important`.  I tried adding those keywords to the config but this does not work:

```
"origin=deb.sury.org,archive=${distro_codename},codename=${distro_codename},Priority=important";
```

> $ unattended-upgrade --dry-run
> ...
> __main__.UnknownMatcherError: Unknown whitelist entry for matcher Priority (token Priority=important)

(same result with lower-case `priority`).

`apt-listchanges` a few days ago showed me this (emphasis mine):

> --- Changes for php8.1 (php8.1 php8.1-bz2 php8.1-cgi php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline php8.1-xml php8.1-zip) ---
> php8.1 (8.1.14-2+0~20230113.32+debian10~1.gbp6a972c) **unstable**; urgency=medium
>
> ** SNAPSHOT build @6a972c330d9c17fa8781d610f444a0d26f00c48b **
>
> * UNRELEASED

I'd rather avoid `unstable` updates if possible, hence I'm trying to filter on only the most important.  Is this possible?